# Running a php script with cron is not working

Tags: php, terminal, cron

I'm trying to run a php script using crontab on MacOS. My crontab looks like this:

`* * * * * /opt/homebrew/bin/php /Users/dan/Documents/test.php`

test.php looks like this:

```php
<?php 

file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/some-file.txt', 'Hello there', FILE_APPEND);

?>
```

But the script doesn't seem to be running. If I enter `/opt/homebrew/bin/php /Users/dan/Documents/test.php` directly into the terminal, then the script runs fine -- `some-file.php` is created in my documents file with the text "Hello there" inside it.

I've also tried adding this cron command into the root user cron tab using `sudo crontab -e`, but that also didn't seem to run the script either.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you confirmed that `__DIR__` has the value you expect when running from `cron`, and that the file isn't simply being written in another directory?

Comment: What user should this run as? What if you don't use PHP but e.g. a shell to write the file?

Answer (score 1):

add some logging to your cron command to see any output or errors

```
* * * * * /opt/homebrew/bin/php /Users/dan/Documents/test.php >> /Users/dan/Documents/cron.log 2>&1
```

If you tried to run the cron job as root (via sudo crontab -e), make sure your script has the appropriate permissions.

You can also create a simpler PHP script that just appends the current date and time to a file, then see if that gets executed. If it does, then the problem may be with the PHP script itself.

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/time_log.txt', $date . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

Update your crontab to run this new script and if you see the date and time getting appended, it means the cron job is working as expected.

But first of all check thi **DIR** like @David says or use full path instead to check if it is writing to proper directory.

Comment: If I run the script from /users/dan, the script runs fine. E.g. If I create the following php script in /users/dan:

`file_put_contents('/users/dan/documents/hello.txt', 'Hello there', FILE_APPEND);`

Then create the cronjob `* * * * * /opt/homebrew/bin/php /Users/danadams/script.php`, it successfully writes to the `hello.txt` file in documents.

But the script doesn't run from documents. E.g. `* * * * * /opt/homebrew/bin/php -f /Users/danadams/documents/script2.php >> /Users/danadams/documents/cron.txt 2>&1`, then I get "Could not open input file: /Users/danadams/documents/script2.php"

Comment: Perhaps there is some sort of permissions issue for the documents folder?